# What is a "fruit protector" as a recipe ingredient?

Tags: fruit

On reading a U. S. book about making one's own cordials, I came across
'1 tablespoon fruit protector' listed in the ingredients of a recipe.

Do you know what fruit protector is called in Britain?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the stuff, but a quick search online shows a couple of brands, and the ingredient lists are similar : dextrose, ascorbic acid, citric acid, and silicon dioxide.  So as strange as it sounds ... it's actually pretty similar to instant lemonade mix.  (although I don't know if the proportions are similar).

Comment: It's a redox agent (antioxidant). Oxygen reacts with it, instead of turning the fruit brown.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge there is only one major brand of fruit/vegetable preserver, Fruit-Fresh. In the U.S. it is often found in the canning section of grocery stores. It is available on Amazon UK ([Fruit-Fresh)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/1440024100-Ball-Fruit-Fresh-Produce-Protector/dp/B000KOSP6M) so you may also be able to find it in local markets.